# $\dim V<\infty$, $\operatorname{char}V\ne2$ and let $w\in\operatorname{Sym}(w)$, then there exists a basis for $V$ which is orthogonal w.r.t. $w$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Consider $\operatorname{Bil}(V)=\{\text{bilinear maps}\ V\times V\rightarrow F\}$. Let $\dim V<\infty$, $\operatorname{char}F\neq 2$, and let $w\in\operatorname{Sym}(V)$, ie. $w$ is symmetric ($w(x,y)=w(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in V$). Then there exists a basis for $V$ which is orthogonal w.r.t. $w$.

A proof is given in the textbook, which *I'm* having trouble understanding.

**Proof:** By induction on $n=\dim V$. If $V=\{0\}$, there's nothing to prove. Also, if $w=0$, every basis is orthogonal, so assume $w\neq 0$. Then $w$ is not skew and hence not alternating.

Let $x_1\in V$ be such that $w(x_1,x_1)\neq0$. Consider the linear form $y(x)=w(x_1,x)$ for $x\in V$. Here $y\in V'\setminus\{0\}$ and hence its nullspace $N(y)=\{x_1\}^\bot$ has dimension $n-1$. By induction it has an orthogonal basis $\{x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ and then $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $V$.

---

We say $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal if $w(x,y)=0$.

For $U\subset V$ then $U^\bot=\{y\in V \mid \forall x\in U: w(x,y)=0$}.

$V'$ denotes the dual space of $V$.

---

Now here are my questions.

- In the case where $n=0$, then $V=\{0\}$ since $V$ must have a neutral additive element. $0$ can't be a basis element or else we wounldn't have unique ways to write elements in $V$ as linear combinations, right? But how does there "exists a basis for $V$ which is orthogonal w.r.t. $w$"? What basis is that?
- Next as we define $y(x)$, why do we mention that $y\in V'\setminus\{0\}$? By writing out the sets, isn't it clear that $N(y)=\{x_1\}^\bot$?
- Why does $\{x_1\}^\bot$ have dimension $n-1$?
- At last, we get that $\{x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $\{x_1\}^\bot$, but why does that imply that $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a basis for $V$? I do however see why it's orthogonal.

Comment: I've just fixed a very serious typo in the proof presented in your post: "$\color{red}{w(x_1,x_1)=0}$" in fact must be "$\color{blue}{w(x_1,x_1)\neq0}$".

Comment: The notation $w\in \text{Sym}(w)$ is weird.  Did you mean $w\in \text{Sym}(V)$?  Also, did you perhaps want to write $\text{char}(F)\neq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some answers.

- The basis of the zero vector space $V=\{0\}$ is the empty set $\varnothing$. This may seem a bit counterintuitive, but if we check we can see that it formally satisfies the definition of a basis.
- To emphasize that $y$ is **NOT** the identically zero functional. That's important because if $y=0$ (in $V'$), i.e if $y$ is the identically zero functional, then its kernel (or null-space) is $\ker(y)=N(y)=\{x_1\}^{\bot}=V$, the entire space $V$, and we can't proceed in any useful way. However, since $w(x_1,x_1)\ne0$, we know that $y(x_1)\neq0$, so $y$ is not the zero functional. Therefore, $\ker(y)=N(y)=\{x_1\}^{\bot}\subsetneq V$, a proper subset of $V$.

  And yes, of course, $N(y)=\{x_1\}^{\bot}$. But once again, the real question is whether it is all of $V$ or not.
- By the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).
- Because they are $n$ linearly independent vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense! About the Rank-Nullity Theorem: We know that $\dim V=n$ since that is the case, we want to show the theorem holds for. Now why is $Rank(y)=1$? I guess we have that $y: V\rightarrow F$, so $Im(y)\subset F$, but $I'm$ not quiet sure why it have dimension $1$? Is it because $F$ at most have dimension $1$, and $N(y)$ is a proper subset of $V$ (so $Rank(y)> 0$)?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Since $\dim F=1$, we know that the rank is either $0$ or $1$. But since we've demonstrated that $w$ is not the zero functional, it's not $0$.